# Diagonalization: Differential Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

The booking being used for this course is *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems* by Lawrence Perko. The problem is as follows:

> > Let the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ have real, distinct eigenvalues. Let $\phi(t,\vec{x_0})$ be the solution to the initial value problem:
> >
> > \begin{eqnarray}
> > \vec{x}'&=&A\vec{x} \\
> > \vec{x(0)}&=&\vec{x_0}
> > \end{eqnarray}
> >     Show that for each fixed $t\in \mathbb{R}$, 
> >     \begin{equation}
> > \lim_{\vec{y_0}\rightarrow \vec{x_0}}\phi(t,\vec{y_o}) = \phi(t,\vec{x_0})
> > \end{equation}

From what I understand:

- Since the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\}$ of $A$ are real and distinct, then the set of corresponding eigenvectors $\{\vec{v_1},...,\vec{v_n}\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the matrix $P=[\vec{v_1}...\vec{v_n}]$ is invertible and $P^{-1}AP=$ diag$[\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n]$.
- Now $A$ is diagonalizable $\rightarrow A = P^{-1}$diag$[\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n]P$.
- Thus we can say:

\begin{align}
\vec{x(t)}=\phi(t,\vec{x_0})= P \text{diag}[e^{\lambda_1 t},...,e^{\lambda_n t}]       P^{-1}\vec{x_0}
\end{align}

Define $P^{-1} = [c_{ij}]$. Thus 
\begin{align}
P^{-1}\vec{x_0} & = \begin{bmatrix}
          \sum_{j=1}^{n}c_{1j}x_{0j} \\
           \vdots\\
\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_{nj}x_{0j}
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

- We are trying to show the solution $\phi(t,\vec{x_0})$ is a continuous function of the initial condition.
- We say a function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ if it is defined for $x\approx x_0$, and given any $\epsilon > 0$, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ for $x\approx x_0$.
- We say a function has the limit $L$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$ if given $\epsilon >0, |f(x)- L| < \epsilon$ for $x\approx x_0$ but not necessary equal to $x_0$.
- If I understand correctly, I want to show for some $\epsilon > 0, |P^{-1}\vec{y_0} - P^{-1}\vec{x_0}|< \epsilon$ for $\vec{y_0}\approx \vec{x_0}$.

Am I on the right track? How would I properly continue from here?

---

Thank you so much for your time and thank you for any feedback you may give in advance.